# How do I get Internal HD graphics to work on 16.04 with dual monitors (external) on a laptop?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, laptop, xrandr, nvidia-prime

any help appreciated. I'm VERY motivated to get this to work :).

I have an MSI with an nVidia 1060 (notebook version) and intel built in graphics. I've tried on Ubuntu 16.04.1 direct, and/or on LinuxMint Cinnamon--same results.

The only way I am able to get the external monitor working is to enable the intel-microcode driver and the nvidia proprietary driver, but I'd like to use Intel driver for graphics and save nVidia for CUDA. I would share my `lspci -H1` results, but lspci apparently creates some sort of a kernel panic (???).

But, here's my `xrandr --query`:

```
selly@numbersix:~$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.01*+
   3200x1800     60.00  
   2880x1620     60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

For completeness here's the output of xrandr using nvidia-375.20: (I ran `sudo prime-select nvidia`)

```
selly@numbersix:~$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6400 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 2560x1440+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 399mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.01*+
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-1 disconnected
  1600x1200 (0x4d) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4e) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x52) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x53) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1024x768 (0x59) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x60) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x69) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

Here is the output of lspci (again after `prime-select nvidia`:

```
selly@numbersix:~$ sudo lspci -H1
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c20 (rev a1)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
3e:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

Comment: FWIW, I finally filed a bug with nVidia and I'm waiting to hear back. nVidia's immediate response was to disable the internal card in the BIOS, which isn't possible in this laptop. I'll post more when I hear more. FWIW, I have now tested on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, LinuxMint 18 and 18.1. I have also tried all PPA-hosted drivers from 367+, and also modified the kernel manually up from 4.4.0 to 4.9 to no avail :(.